# Alter row_format to dynamic

Tags: mysql

What is the MySQL statement to alter the `row_format` to `dynamic`?

I am not sure how I am supposed to do it (i.e. using the `information_schema` or by using a table `ALTER`).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try

```
ALTER TABLE `test`  ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: I tried, not sure why but when i check table properties, it's still compact although the mysql statement executes successfully. i'm using wamp 2.1

Comment: @airnet, im happy it working for you, have a read of this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html

Comment: I tried, but I am having an error: ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Answer (score 2):

The method I've used, based on the [current Oracle docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format.html), is because the `COMPACT` tables I have were only set based on the default, which has now changed. This is on a MariaDB 10.2 system for me, but will work on modern MySQL systems.

Specifically, ensure default is DYNAMIC (or the format you need):

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format=DYNAMIC;
```

Then OPTIMIZE the tables you need to change;

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE database.tablename;
```

This works, because the `row_format` is updated to the server default on an "operation that rebuilds a table silently", to quote the documentation.